# i am getting the error when trying to run query

Tags: sql, db2

Query is:

```
Update maximo.item
set staus ='OBSOLETE'
where itemnum='343900-40' and siteid='abc';
```

> SQL Error: the numeric literal "40" is not valid.. SQLCODE=-103, SQLSTATE=42606, DRIVER= 4.26.12

Comment: This error message seems completely unrelated. There is no 40 in that query. Are you sure it is not another query that leads to the error?

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: From the error message I gather this is DB2. I've tagged your request with this DBMS. Please correct this in case I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Thorsten,

query is Update maximo.item set staus ='OBSOLETE' where itemnum='343900-40' and siteid='abc';

Comment: in the database-table  maximo.item,  what is the column datatype of "item"?  Your code presumes it is char or varchar, but the error code suggests you are mistaken.

Comment: Is `itemnum` a numeric type? Then the error would make sense, since `'34900-40'` is not a number.

Comment: How do you run the query?